# Is there a way to not re-train my NN every time?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pycharm

If I have to make only a/some prediction(s), do I need to re-train my NN every time? Or I can, pardon me if this is silly, "save" the training and only do the test?
Currently I'm using Pycharm, but I've seen that with other IDEs, like Spyder, you can execute selected lines of code, in that case how does the NN keeps the training without the need to re-train?
Sorry if those question are too naive.

Comment: That is not naive at all. You are just a newcomer so it is only natural. Save your weight matrices to a file. And when you are testing create your model and read from weight file to assign each layer's corresponding weight values. You are good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to re-train your NN every time. Just save your model parameters into a file and load to make new predictions.

Are you using any machine learning framework like Tensorflow or Keras? In Keras is very easy to implement this, there are two methods, first you can save model during training using the [Callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/) and second, are possible to use `your_model_name.save('file_name.h5')` and then load with `load_model('file_name.h5`) to do some predictions. Use `your_model_name.prediction(x)`.

By the way, [there is a nice guide](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/) to how you can properly save the full model architecture or model weights.

EDIT: For both methods you can use `load_model`, is very simple!

Comment: Yes, I'm using Keras and thanks for your answer, it was really helpful!